# matlab audio frequency after audio concatenation

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I have written code for concatenation of audio files. The audio files are recorded sounds of a person. Here is the code

```
  [y1,Fs] = audioread('D:/1.wav');
  [y2,Fs] = audioread('D:/2.wav');
  [y3,Fs] = audioread('D:/3.wav');
  y4=vertcat(y1, y2);
  y4=vertcat(y4, y2);
```

It works fine. The output file when plotted looks like this

[image: Frequency Plot]

The image above has different frequencies for each alphabet when plotted. The output of concatenation after merging has different pitch frequency for each alphabet. how can i attend same pitch frequency so that the output of audio appears to be more natural.

Comment: You can resample your data using [`resample`](https://mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html) or [`interp1`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html?searchHighlight=interp1&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) to a common sample frequency before concatenation.

Comment: @m7913d resample changes audio quality

Comment: Is your new sample frequency high enough?

Comment: Confused what’s going on. You concatenate two files but there are three utterances in the time-vs-amplitude plot.  Are you saying they have different frequency content (i.e., all three utterances are nominally the same?), or are you saying they’re sampled at different frequencies? What’s different about what?

Comment: @AhmedFasih recording for each alphabet is different. hence there is variance in pitch. how can i attend same pitch frequency so that the output audio appears to be more natural.

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by “natural”. If three different speakers say the same thing, their vocal chords will result in different frequencies being present—do you want to make them all sound like the same person? Or…?

Comment: @AhmedFasih yes sir, i want to make them sound like same person.

Comment: Making a speaker sound like someone else—I haven’t worked on that specific problem but I would think it is a much harder problem than a StackOverflow answer can contain! Some recent work has been done on audio style transfer using deep learning (https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/neural-style-audio-tf), and you can always do what audio engineers do—adjust frequency subbands over small intervals.

Comment: @AhmedFasih what if audio is from same person and that is concatenated. I mean if each alphabet is recorded individually and then concatenated. Then how can we show that  the concatenated word sounds like naturally spoken. I mean it must sound not feel like the output audio is concatenated.

Comment: @AhmedFasih here is the link http://iwammexico.com/voice.rar

Comment: @AhmedFasih can u help me with this please.

Comment: I listened to the concatenated output but am still unclear what exactly you want to do. The first utterance has more background noise, while the second and third sound similar. Do you want to remove the background noise of the first…?